# Dual Boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 no GRUB appearing going directly to WIndows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I was trying with my friend to Install Ubuntu 14.04 In Dual Boot Mode With Windows 8.1 UEFI in my new Toshiba laptop. The installation of Ubuntu was finished successfully. However when I rebooted (with secure boot disabled) it is not showing any GRUB menu and directly going to Windows. It is, I guess the similar situation to the following : [Boot repair : error occurred](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508422/boot-repair-error-occurred). I tried to fix this problem exactly the same way by using Boot-repair. It finished with the following error message.

```
"An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8249722/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to: boot.repair@gmail.com

You can now reboot your computer."
```

Switching off the fast startup did not help as someone advised on forum previously. Does anybody know what the problem is ? I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: Hi user, did you read and follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported completely?